# Question using Ext's update() instead of dom.innerHTML

Tags: extjs, innerhtml

I have a question concerning the performance, reliability, and best practice method of using Extjs's update() method, versus directly updating the innerHTML of the dom of an Ext element.

Consider the two statements:

```
Ext.fly('element-id').dom.innerHTML = 'Welcome, Dude!';
```

and

```
Ext.fly('element.id').update('Welcome, Dude!', false);
```

I don't need to `eval()` any script, and I'm certain that `update()` takes into consideration any browser quirks.

Also, does anyone know if using:

```
Ext.fly('element-id').dom.innerHTML
```

is the same as

```
d.getElementById('element-id').innerHTML
```

?
Browser and platform compatibility are important, and if the two are fundamentally the same, then ditching `Ext.element.dom.innerHTML` altogether for `update()` would probably be my best solution.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need to load scripts dynamically into your updated html or process a callback after the update, then the two methods you've outlined are equivalent.  The bulk of the code in `update()` adds the script loading and callback capabilities.  Internally, it simply sets the innerHTML to do the content replacement.

`Ext.fly().dom` returns a plain DOM node, so yes, it is equivalent to the result of `getElementById()` in terms of the node it points to.  The only subtlety to understand is the difference between Ext.fly() and Ext.get().  Ext.fly() returns a shared instance of the node wrapper object (a flyweight).  As such, that instance might later point to a different node behind the scenes if any other code calls Ext.fly(), including internal Ext code.  As such, the result of a call to Ext.fly() should only be used for atomic operations and not reused as a long-lived object.  `Ext.get().dom` on the other hand returns a new, unique object instance, and in that sense, would be more like getElementById().

Comment: So, to put it basically, unless I'm wanting to process a callback or eval some scripts, then using `update()` is more or less overkill. Am I understanding that correctly?

My main concern is browser compatibility. So in those terms, does `update()` have any advantage over `Ext.fly().dom`?

Thanks!!

Comment: It makes no difference.  It's not overkill -- it's exactly the same.  There is no difference in compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered your own question: *"Browser and platform compatibility are important, and if the two are fundamentally the same, then ditching Ext.element.dom.innerHTML altogether for update() would probably be my best solution."*  JS libraries are intended (in part) to abstract browser differences; update is an example.

@bmoeskau wrote above, update() provides additional functionality that you don't need right for your current problem.  Nevertheless, update is a good choice.